# Multiple selected files in openfinedialog c#

Tags: c#, fileopendialog

I would like to select multiple excel file using openfiledialog,the output of each excell has to be stored at datatable, and i have to gather the datatable in dataset in order to use it as datasource of gridview in my application, i use windows desktop 4.5 ,thaks

Answer (score 2):

> Multiple selected files in openfinedialog c#

Use [`OpenFileDialog.Multiselect Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) to select multiple files and for the rest of your stuff you need to write code.